# Why does the user drop-down info shows the amount of revisions that were made to your posts?

Tags: support, revisions-list, activity-dropdown

..and not amount of revisions that I made?

Every other item listed there reflects actions I did:

- reputation
- favorites
- votes

It seems a bit strange, that the amount of revisions reflects actions of other users.
When I click on revisions I see revisions other people made to my posts.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot?  The dropdown currently shows revisions I've made on my posts, and [your activity->revisions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/644450/oers?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions) seems to show revisions **you have made** (ex. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/138577), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8184777/revisions), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/138570)), which is an action you did.  I can't see any revisions on your revisions tab that were revisions on your post from other users.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I provided the screenshot. And sorry I mis-worded the question a bit ;)

Comment: Thanks - Though I should have been able to figure it out without it; I just failed to click through the first time because I thought I knew where it was going and thought you were seeing some sort of bug. Should have been more careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'revisions' tab on the dropdown correlates with your **responses** -> revisions tab at  https://stackoverflow.com/users/644450/oers?tab=responses#page_1-rfilter_revisions
(Note: Visible only to you):

[image: responses]

rather than your **activity** -> revisions tab:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/644450/oers?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions
(Note: Public):

[image: activity]

I disagree that the dropdown reflects actions you did:

- reputation: This is reputation you've earned, which is an action by other users on your profile.  You get it by posting, but it's not automatic.
- favorites: These are changes made by other users to your favorites.  The hovertext says "X new answers or comments on your favorites today/this week/this month.
- votes: This is, in fact, the votes you've cast on other answers and questions, not an action by other users on your profile.  It might be here because it's something you'd want to know at-a-glance if you're approaching the vote limit.

If you want to see revisions you've made, you'll have to use the [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644450/oers?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions).  I think that revisions that you have made are more interesting and should stay in the dropdown - you can remember the revisions you've made to others' posts, but the revisions others make to your posts are probably news to you.